Kinetic energy of an ellipsoid
I am trying to solve the following exercise, taken from Landau's Mechanics:

Find the kinetic energy of a homogeneous triaxial ellipsoid, rotating around one of its axes (AB, fig. 44), while the latter in turn rotates around the perpendicular CD passing through the center of the ellipsoid.


I think there are two angular velocities to consider: the one related to the rotation of the ellipsoid around AB, and the one related to the rotation of AB around CD; the former has the direction of AB, the latter has the direction of CD, while there is no angular velocity around the remaining principal axis of inertia. Thus, since the center of mass of the ellipsoid is at rest, the kinetic energy of the ellipsoid should be the rotational kinetic energy, that is:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\left(I_2 \dot \theta^2+I_3 \dot\varphi^2\right)$$
where $I_2$ and $I_3$ are the principal moments of inertia, related to the axis CD and AB respectively.
However, I do not understand why Landau says that the projections of the angular velocity $\Omega$ are: $\dot \theta\cos\varphi$, $\dot \theta \sin\varphi$ and $\dot \varphi$, and then the kinetic energy is:
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\left(I_1\cos^2\varphi+I_2\sin^2\varphi\right)\dot \theta^2+\frac{1}{2}I_3\dot \varphi^2.$$
What am I missing?

$I_1$ and $I_2$ are rotating with $\varphi$, so the $\theta$ axis is a combination of the two.

Why CD is rotating?

Your earlier comment is correct.

If my earlier comment is correct, then is it true that the angular velocity related to the rotation with respect to CD indicates the direction of CD, which is also rotating due to the rotation with respect to AB?

But do I have to consider the principal axis of inertia fixed? If so, then the angular velocity related to the first rotation could not have a fixed direction.

The CD rotation axis depends on $\varphi$. In other words, it is rotating in the 12 plane in the body frame.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Then, for the same reason, AB is rotating in the 13 plane. Why the first angular velocity is not $\Omega=(\dot \varphi \cos\theta,0, \dot \varphi \sin\theta)$ ?

"AB is rotating in the 13 plane" This is false. The AB angular velocity is always along axis 3 in the body frame.

Why AB is not rotating in the body frame?

The OP wants to understand how the two rotations combine in this scenario. They aren't asking us to do or check a calculation. Voting to reopen.

@user1255055 Because both AB and axis 3 are rotating together with $\dot{\theta}$. So they are always parallel. The same cannot be said for CD. CD is not rotating with $\dot{\varphi}$. It always points downwards. The two rotations are not equivalent in terms of order. $\dot{\varphi}$ is applied after $\dot{\theta}$. Reversing the order results in a different effect.

@user1255055 The whole point is that axes 1 and 2 are rotating in a vertical plane. So $\dot{\theta}$ has time-varying components when decomposed.

Let $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1, \hat{\mathbf{x}}_2, \hat{\mathbf{x}}_3$ denote the body-fixed principal axes. There are two angular velocities: $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{AB}$ and $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{CD}$. It is clear that $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{AB}$ always points along $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_3$, giving angular momentum $I_3\dot{\varphi}$. However, $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{CD}$ does not. Due to the rotation about $AB$, it lies parallel to the plane spanned by $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2$ and is not always parallel to either one of them. It is a linear combination of the two. Equivalently, in the body frame, the vector $\boldsymbol{\omega}_{CD}$ (i.e. the "downward" direction $CD$) is rotating in the $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1$-$\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2$ plane with angular velocity $\dot{\varphi}$. So we need to resolve it into components, giving
$$\boldsymbol{\omega}_{CD} = \dot{\theta}\cos\varphi \hat{\mathbf{x}}_1 + \dot{\theta}\sin\varphi\hat{\mathbf{x}}_2$$
choosing that $\varphi$ be the angle between $\hat{\mathbf{x}}_1$ and $CD$. The rest is straightforward using addition of angular velocities.

$\def \b {\mathbf}$

Landau used  this transformation matrix between the local ellipsoid system and inertial system
$$\b R= \b R_x(\theta)\,\b R_z(\phi)=
 \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 1&0&0\\ 0&\cos \left( 
\theta \right) &-\sin \left( \theta \right) \\ 0&
\sin \left( \theta \right) &\cos \left( \theta \right) \end {array}
 \right]
\, \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} \cos \left( \phi \right) &-\sin \left( 
\phi \right) &0\\ \sin \left( \phi \right) &\cos
 \left( \phi \right) &0\\  0&0&1\end {array} \right] 
$$
from here you obtain the angular velocity given in local ellipsoid system
$$\b\omega= \left[ \begin {array}{c} \cos \left( \phi \right) \dot\theta 
\\ -\sin \left( \phi \right) \dot\theta 
\\ \dot\phi \end {array} \right]
$$
the kinetic energy is
$$T=\frac 12 \b\omega^T\,\b I\,\b\omega$$
with
$$\b I=   \left[ \begin {array}{ccc} { I_1}&0&0\\ 0&{ I_2
}&0\\ 0&0&{I_3}\end {array} \right] 
$$
you obtain
$$T=\frac{1}{2}\left(I_1\cos^2\varphi+I_2\sin^2\varphi\right)\dot \theta^2+\frac{1}{2}I_3\dot \varphi^2.$$

The angular velocity
$$\left[ \begin {array}{ccc} 0&-\omega_{{z}}&\omega_{{y}}
\\  \omega_{{z}}&0&-\omega_{{x}}\\  
-\omega_{{y}}&\omega_{{x}}&0\end {array} \right]=\b R^T\,\b{\dot{R}}$$

Then $I$ is the matrix of the tensor of inertia with respect to the principal axes of inertia $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ of the ellipsoid, and $I_1$, $I_2$ and $I_3$ are the principal moments of inertia of the ellipsoid (that is, the eigenvalues of the tensor of inertia)?

@user1255055 . this is correct
